# how to include css & js in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

```
 <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">



<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider-min.js</name></action>


 <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>

</block>
```

I include this code at page.xml..
but ccs & js is not included to follow this code . please help me..

Comment: <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
 
 
 
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider-min.js</name></action>


 <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>

 
 
 
 
</block>  i use it.. but not working

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange! Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Answer (score 2):

In your app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout folder, create a local.xml and add the following:

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.flexslider-min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/flexslider.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

If the file already exists, add the contents of `<layout>` (and if `<default>` already exists you can add the content of that) to the file.

You don't need to add the flexslider and the minified version (the -min.js file), just the minified is fine.